# Find and Replace with grep and sed in OSX

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I am trying to replace the string `#archive` in a bunch of files in the same directory with `~archive`. My filenames have spaces in them and are rather long. I checked and someone said that I have to invoke grep with -Z and xargs with -0. And so I did.

The current terminal command I have is this:

```
grep -lZ '#archive' ~/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/* | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's|#archive|~archive|g'
```

And the output I get is this:

```
sed: /Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20130824_1553_I_Kino Interesting Books.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131003_1011_R_ExpensesOct13.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131111_1205_RI_SocialConnect.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131111_2233_I_GymNov13Dec13.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131112_1121_I_LifeChallenge.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131112_1242__PaperlessLiving.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131112_1243__Polymath.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131112_1327__ORDPlanning.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/20131124_1126__YunheProjectExcel.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/Contact Information.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/Excruciatingly Useful Shortcuts.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/How does this thing work?.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/Mail Migration.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/Markdownify.txt
/Users/bobthebuilder/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/This is the title of a note.txt
: File name too long
```

And nothing is replaced.

I also tried:

```
| => grep -l --null '#archive' ~/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/* | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's|#archive|~archive|g'
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use the `-i` arg for `sed`, you will need to put the command string after a `-e`.

```
grep -l --null '#archive' ~/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/* | xargs -0 sed -e 's|#archive|~archive|g' -i ""
```

However, @NeronLeVelo's answer is also correct, and simpler if you don't need recursion (which you aren't using).

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I also had another problem with my ~/.bash_profile causing the `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`. I added `export LC_CTYPE=C 
export LANG=C` to my bash_profile and your code worked great after that!

Answer (score 5):

if files are in the same folder

```
sed -i "" 's/#archive/~archive/' ~/dropbox/documents/notes/Archive/*
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I chose @gaige in the end as I want to recycle the code for cases where I need recursion.